# CodeIgniter URL Rewrite then get data select?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite URLs. I've already removed `index.php`. But;

`site.com/controller/function?haber=deneme_haberi`

or

`site.com/controller/function?cat=teknoloji&haber=deneme_haberi`

I want to;

`site.com/controller/function/deneme_haberi`

or

`site.com/controller/function/teknoloji/deneme_haberi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, in Codeigniter, if you send the URL

site.com/controller1/my_function/teknoloji/deneme_haberi, you directly map the segments after the name of the controller as parameters in the function:

```
class Controller1 extends CI_Controller { 

[...]

public function my_function( $cat, $haber )
{
    echo $cat;
    echo $haber;
}
```

`$cat` and `$haber` will have the second and third segment values respectively, printing 'teknoloji' and 'deneme_haberi'. It's important you notice that the order is important when you write the url, because it'll be the order in wich you'll send the parameters.